# Slow running MySQL query - how to optimize?

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I'm running a query, and struggling to understand why MySQL is runing it so slowly. I've included the actual queries and the EXPLAIN in 3 scenarios below.

The first query is very slow to run (23 seconds), but removing just one field (Query 2) from the where clause causes the query to run in 0.010s. This is a TinyInt field (essentially a boolean 0/1 is stored).

projects -> hasMany -> milestones -> hasMany -> tasks

task_wishlist is a pivot table between tasks and wishlists

**QUERY 1**

```
SELECT `tasks`.*,
        task_wishlist.description AS item_description,
        task_wishlist.created_at AS item_created_at
FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id`
LEFT JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
WHERE `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021'
  AND `tasks`.`active` = '1'
  AND `projects`.`active` = '1'
  AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'
ORDER BY `task_wishlist`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 25;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 25  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 23.072 sec. (+ 0.040 sec. network) */
```

**Query 1 EXPLAIN:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: projects
   partitions: NULL
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 997
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: milestones
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,milestones_project_id_foreign
          key: milestones_project_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.projects.id
         rows: 3
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tasks
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,tasks_milestone_id_foreign
          key: tasks_milestone_id_foreign
      key_len: 5
          ref: fusion.milestones.id
         rows: 5
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: task_wishlist
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: task_wishlist_wishlist_id_foreign,task_wishlist_task_id_foreign
          key: task_wishlist_task_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.tasks.id
         rows: 100
     filtered: 0.28
        Extra: Using where
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.01 sec)
```

**Query 2 (remove milestones.active)**

```
SELECT `tasks`.*,
       task_wishlist.description AS item_description,
       task_wishlist.created_at AS item_created_at
FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id`
LEFT JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
WHERE `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021'
  AND `tasks`.`active` = '1'
  AND `projects`.`active` = '1'
  /*AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'*/
ORDER BY `task_wishlist`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 25;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 25  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.028 sec. (+ 0.010 sec. network) */
```

**Query 2 Explain:**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: task_wishlist
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: task_wishlist_wishlist_id_foreign,task_wishlist_task_id_foreign
          key: task_wishlist_wishlist_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 7224
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tasks
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,tasks_milestone_id_foreign
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.task_wishlist.task_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: milestones
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,milestones_project_id_foreign
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.tasks.milestone_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: NULL
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: projects
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.milestones.project_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

**Query 3: remove projects.active = 1**

```
SELECT `tasks`.*,
       task_wishlist.description AS item_description,
       task_wishlist.created_at AS item_created_at
FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id`
LEFT JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
WHERE `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021'
  AND `tasks`.`active` = '1'
  /*AND `projects`.`active` = '1'*/
  AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'
ORDER BY `task_wishlist`.`created_at` DESC
LIMIT 25;
/* Affected rows: 0  Found rows: 25  Warnings: 0  Duration for 1 query: 0.027 sec. (+ 4.031 sec. network) */
```

**Query 3 Explain**

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: task_wishlist
   partitions: NULL
         type: ref
possible_keys: task_wishlist_wishlist_id_foreign,task_wishlist_task_id_foreign
          key: task_wishlist_wishlist_id_foreign
      key_len: 4
          ref: const
         rows: 7224
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index condition; Using where; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: tasks
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,tasks_milestone_id_foreign
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.task_wishlist.task_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: milestones
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.tasks.milestone_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 10.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: projects
   partitions: NULL
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: fusion.milestones.project_id
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
4 rows in set, 1 warning (0.00 sec)
```

What can I do to make this query run properly with all `active` fields included?

Comment: Did you try to create any non-unique index for each of these fields to see if that helps at all?

Comment: This format of explain is difficult to read, but the amount of rows that MySQL deals with is low. This implies there could be an I/O problem. Are you running a mechanical hard drive and default MySQL configuration? There's an additional profiling mechanism available in MySQL, called `profiling`. `SET PROFILING = 1; Your query goes here ; SHOW PROFILE FOR QUERY 1; SET PROFILING = 0;`. This will show you all steps that MySQL undertakes behind the scenes. Guessing blindly: your `innodb_buffer_pool_size` is too low, so MySQL needs to wait for HDD to complete its I/O, which is slow.

Comment: What are the table and index definitions?

Comment: My understanding is that indexes on boolean-type fields are not of any benefit. There is no I/O problem - this is a mysql optimization issue - notice the `using temporary` in the first explain, but not the others.

Comment: @JonoB - Yes, indexing a boolean is usually useless.  However a 'composite' index starting with a boolean _may_ be beneficial.  (I don't see an example of such in _this_ Question.)

Comment: @JonoB - how come there is no I/O problem if your query inspects a tiny amount of rows which takes 23 seconds? I/O problem _means_ there's an optimization issue. Not fiddling with query but with your MySQL instance config. I hinted about steps you can take to assert what _really_ takes up time. Now, I can't make you accept my help nor will I go head over heels to convince you to actually try something in order to determine what's going on behind the scenes. I probably went ahead of myself with the conclusion there's an I/O problem (there is, you'll conclude that in a while). Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

One fact you need to relize is that your query in fact is doing simple INNER JOINs but not LEFT JOINS.
The [Left outer join](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Left_outer_join) basically works in the same way as inner join exept that it returns NULLs if the join-condition does not find any matching row in the "right" table.
But all NULLs in your query are filtered out by conditions in the WHERE clause, please examine closely the query:

```
FROM `tasks`
LEFT JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id`
LEFT JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
WHERE `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021'  
  AND `tasks`.`active` = '1'  
  AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'
  AND `projects`.`active` = '1'
```

- nulls from `LEFT JOIN task_wishlist` are filtered out by `WHERE task_wishlist.wishlist_id = '527021'`
- nulls from `LEFT JOIN milestones` are filtered out by `WHERE milestones.active = '1'`
- nulls from `LEFT JOIN projects` are filtered out by `WHERE projects.active = '1'`

MySql is aware of that and it internally rewrites your query into INNER JOIN query:

```
FROM `tasks`
INNER JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id`
INNER JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id`
INNER JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id`
WHERE `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021'  
  AND `tasks`.`active` = '1'  
  AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'
  AND `projects`.`active` = '1'
```

---

If you remove (comment) some condition from the WHERE clause, this "activates" corresponding LEFT JOIN part of the query, so semantics of the query changes and it's resultset also changes. It does not make any sense to compare a performance of such queries, because they are frankly different, and in fact you are comparing apples to oranges.

---

Since the query is doing simple INNER JOINs, you can rewrite it to this one:

```
FROM `tasks`
INNER JOIN `task_wishlist` ON `tasks`.`id` = `task_wishlist`.`task_id` 
                                         AND `task_wishlist`.`wishlist_id` = '527021' 

INNER JOIN `milestones` ON `tasks`.`milestone_id` = `milestones`.`id` 
                                                AND `milestones`.`active` = '1'

INNER JOIN `projects` ON `milestones`.`project_id` = `projects`.`id` 
                                                 AND `projects`.`active` = '1'
```

and now in the conditions above you can easily see "pairs" of columns which are used during a join:

- projects.id + projects.active
- milestones.id + milestones.active
- task_wishlist.task_id + task_wishlist.wishlist_id

Try to add a multicolum indexes on there "pairs", one example for `projects` table:

```
CREATE INDEX xxx ON projects( id, active )
```

If `id` column is also a primary key, then it may be enoung to add indexes only on single `active` column instead of multicolumn `(id, active)` since [in InnoDB, each record in a secondary index contains the primary key columns for the row, as well as the columns specified for the secondary index.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-index-types.html)

You must experiment yourself.

Comment: Philosophically, `ON` should _only_ say how the tables relate to each other.  `WHERE` should contain any filtering.  For `INNER JOIN`, the Optimizer does not care.  For `LEFT JOIN` there is a semantic difference.

Answer (score 1):

You say `task_wishlist` is a many-to-many mapping table between `tasks` and `wishlists`?  I'll bet it does not have decent indexes.  Follow the tips here:

http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

If that does not suffice, then come back with `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for each of the tables.